# Unwanted output in a file handling program(concatenate files)

Tags: c, file-io, command-line-arguments

I read this code in the K&R C programming book. I get these weird boxes in place of words. Why so? Also please explain the if statement of this program why did he passed argv as a parameter during fileopen. I have opened files with "path" instead of argv but this command line vector argument makes it worse for me to understand. What is *argv[] here? I don't think i haven't fed any string to argv[index] so far. Its little confusing for me. Thanks in advance.

[image: What are these weird symbols i wrote words here]

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* cat: concatenate files, version 1 */
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
void filecopy(FILE *, FILE*);
if(argc==1) /*No optional argument so printing stdin and stdout*/
       filecopy(stdin, stdout);
while(--argc0)
       if((fp= fopen(*++argv, "r")) == NULL){
             printf("Cat: can't open %s\n", *argv);
             return 1;
       }else{
             filecopy(fp, stdout);
             fclose(fp);
       }
return 0;
}

/*filecopy program to copy file a to b*/
void filecopy(FILE *a, FILE *b){
while(c=getc(a) != EOF)
      putc(c,b);
}
```

Comment: The litany of things wrong in this code is long. `argv[]` is an array of `char*`, not `int*`. `argc0` isn't even valid as an identifier, `c=getc(a) != EOF` doesn't do what you likely want it to, and it doesn't matter anyway, because `c` isn't a valid identifier either. What toolchain are you using that actually *accepted* this?

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong here but didn't do that i main program

Comment: @WhozCraig i was just typing normal words(strings) in terminal hoping it would concatenate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you made some errors copying the program from K&R..
..and they are causing your problems.

Specifically, this code:

```
while(c=getc(a) != EOF)
  putc(c,b);
```

Should be:

```
int c;    

while((c=getc(a)) != EOF)
    putc(c,b);
```

The issue is that the assignment operator (`=`) has a lower order of evaluation 
than the not-equal operator (`!=`) .